# Can all types of devil fruit be awakened?

Tags: one-piece

Can all types of devil fruit like Paramecia Type, Zoan type, and Logia be used in the awakening mode that Doflamingo mentioned and used against Luffy?

For e.g. let's take an Ancient Zoan type **DF** user like captain X-Drake, can he achieve an awakening stage for his type of **DF**?

Comment: FYI, X-Drake has an Ancient Zoan fruit rather than a Mythical Zoan DF... We only know of (to my knowledge) two canon Mythical Zoan Fruits: Hito HIto no mi model Daibutsu (Buddha statue) and Marco's Pheonix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this point it is still unknown if all DFs will be able to unlock an awakened state. Right now we only know of Donquixote Doflamingo (Paramecia) and the Impel Down guards (Zoan). There is one more but this might still be manga-only (I haven't watched the anime in a while) so I put it at the bottom of my answer and marked it as a spoiler.

I would assume that an awakened ancient zoan DF user, like Drake-X, would still enjoy the same benefits as an awakened regular zoan DF. These benefits are increased strength and durability which also leads to a higher recovery rate. This information can also be found on the [wiki](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Devil_Fruit#Awakening), please keep in mind that this article contains spoilers so thread carefully.

There haven't been any logia devil fruits shown to have an awakened state yet.

> Charlotte Katakuri has an awakened devil fruit as well but this is a paramecia DF that acts like a logia DF. The benefit he got from awakening his DF power is the same as Doffy's i.e. turning his environment into the element he can control.

Comment: I don't recall where  increased healing was mentioned if you can provide a source plz

Comment: @HummingDev I have added a link to the wiki, apparently it's not really increased healing but rather a higher recovery rate due to increased durability.

Comment: @HummingDev Chp 544 Crocodile says that their "powers of recovery" are enhanced which people are taking to mean healing.